# In sklearn.metrics.classification_report what does accuracy mean?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, data-science, sklearn-pandas

In a sklearn classification report like this (only shows row of interest):

|  | precision | recall | f1-score | support |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| accuracy |  |  | 0.93 | 2500 |

What does accuracy mean? Is it the same as 'accuracy_score'? If so, why is it in the f1-score column? If not, why do precision and recall not have an accuracy value?

I tested it, and it seems to correspond to the same value as accuracy_score, so how does it relate to the f1-score?

Comment: this function computes subset accuracy: the set of labels predicted for a sample must exactly match the corresponding set of labels in y_true.
The docs https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

Comment: @shanecandoit First of all thank you, but I think my question was targeted at something a little different. Not 'what does 'accuracy_score' do?', but rather 'Why is it a value in the 'f1-score' column?'.